# Is there a JavaScript or jQuery event named bind?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I found a code snippet that binds a few events to an object, one of these events is named "bind". Is there really such an event? Looking around, I just can't find one.

```
jQuery(".some-selector").on("keyup bind cut copy paste", function() { ... });
```

I am thinking that is a mistake from whoever wrote that code... Would that be correct?

Comment: Yeah.. i guess there's no such events. That would have came from a typo.

Comment: It could also be a custom event.

Comment: @Bondye that's the bind method, not an event

Comment: There is no bind event by default, but it could be raised manually elsewhere in the code using a custom event name: `trigger('bind');`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without seeing the rest of the code it's hard to say.
Using jQuery you can create and trigger arbitrarily named events, see the fiddle below:

```js
var t = $('#t');

t.on('click', function () {
  t.trigger('bind');
});

t.on('bind', function () {
  alert("Bind called");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="t">Click</button>
```

So it could very well be that the above code catches an event triggered somewhere else.

Comment: Ah... well, so I searched for `trigger()` and could not find one with an event called `bind` (or a variable if that matter). So I think that I can remove those!

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not a valid DOM event.

For a complete list, take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events)

Comment: a) What do DOM elements have to do with *events*? b) Who is upvoting this?

Comment: I did not mention DOM elements, I listed the available DOM *events*. I did not realize, that the OP could also be looking for custom events, as the other events in the event binder are all valid DOM events.

Answer (score -3):

Yes there is a bind method in javascript prototype.

For details check..
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: That's a method *not* an event. The OP was asking about a bind *event*